# RegEx for double conditions: max length and contains times subsequence br

Tags: php, regex

I need to select a part of string with regex checking for those two conditions:

1. max length is lets say 15
2. has max number of a given sub-sequence like in my case "br" 2 times

I could do this with if conditions but I was hoping to find a regex for that.
so for example:

- 1234567br89 => 1234567br89
- 12br34br56br7 => 12br34br56
- 1234567br8901234567 => 1234567br890123

I need this to implement php function limiting display of long comments like max 15 characters and 3 lines or so. using preg_match().

Comment: can someone tell me why i get **a match for /^(.*?br)/** and **nothing for /^(.*?br.*?br)/** on this same string : "Lorem ipsum placerat ante aenean non <br />
libero mi phasellus senectus, varius <br />
suscipit cursus neque curae hac praesent <br /> 
 lobortis lacinia et, condimentum blandit n <br /> 
ec orci habitant potenti integer commodo."

Comment: works for me in phpfiddle

Comment: Worked on fiddle too here. but on php 5.5.12 and wamp 2.5 not. i need a break. some may have suggestions may be please..

Comment: Nothing I can specifically point to, but I'm guessing that the regex parsing may be old or something. Sorry can't help beyond telling you to just read patch notes to maybe see if they changed anything.

Comment: well i finally did this half regex half substr solution like on this [picture](https://postimg.org/image/l9t4fsxo3/). but can you please tell me why i get the correct result on $m[1] and not $m[0] which has a <br too much for the given regex? is that a normal behavior? or i miss some bug here?

Comment: $m[1] is your first capture group, while $m[0] is the overall line captured. From your regex and given example $m[0] is looking for 3 <br while $m[1] is looking for 2 <br AND everything up until it finds a <br (if it can't find it then it's until newline or EOF).

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
(?=^.{0,15}(.*$))(?|((?:(?:(?!\1$|br).)*br(?:(?!\1$|br).)*){1,2})|(.{0,15})(?=\1$))
```

It captures first 15 characters (or less if there is less characters in total) within a lookahead construct `(?=...)` then checks if there are zero, one or 2 occurrences of `br` at most following recent captured characters.

If there are no `br`s in first 15 characters then the other side of alternation is looked `(.{0,15})(?=\1$)` and if one or two `br`s are placed there first side of alternation succeeds `(?:(?:(?!\1$|br).)*br(?:(?!\1$|br).)*){1,2})`

Second capturing group contains desired chunk of input string.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/fE5lX0/1)